# Error when I push MySQL data with onPostExecute

Tags: java, android

I'm new at programming. I'm doing a login system, but when I log in, I get that error. I don’t know how to solve it. And I have one more question: Is making a login system with chat and friends (add, Remove) system too hard?

Because I want to do that, but I just started programming one week ago, can I do this?

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: complete.lyne.myapplication, PID: 18933
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2
at complete.lyne.myapplication.Login$SolicitaDados.onPostExecute(Login.java:110)
at complete.lyne.myapplication.Login$SolicitaDados.onPostExecute(Login.java:91)
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:660)
at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:677)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Here is my code:

```
package complete.lyne.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;

// import br.com.simplepass.loading_button_lib.customViews.CircularProgressButton;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText loginEmail, loginSenha;
    Button btLogar;
    TextView refCadastrar;

    String url = "";
    String parametro = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        loginEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.loginEmail);
        loginSenha = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.loginSenha);
        btLogar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btLogar);
        refCadastrar = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.refCadastrar);

        refCadastrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent abreCadastro = new Intent(Login.this, Cadastro.class);
                startActivity(abreCadastro);
            }
        });

        btLogar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)
                        getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

                if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {

                    String email = loginEmail.getText().toString();
                    String senha = loginSenha.getText().toString();

                    if(email.isEmpty() && senha.matches(".*[a-z].*")) {
                        loginEmail.setError("Insira seu endereço de Email.");
                    } else if (email.matches(".*[a-z].*") && senha.isEmpty()) {
                        loginSenha.setError("Insira sua Senha.");
                    } else if (email.isEmpty() && senha.isEmpty()) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nenhum campo pode ficar vazio.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {

                        // Casa
                        url = "http://192.168.1.100/lyne/logar.php";

                        // Badran
                        // url = "http://172.16.2.15/lyne/logar.php";

                        parametro = "email=" + email + "&senha=" + senha;

                        new SolicitaDados().execute(url);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nenhuma conexão com a Internet foi encontrada.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private class SolicitaDados extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

                return Conexao.postDados(urls[0], parametro);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String resultado) {

           if(resultado != null) {
                if (resultado.contains("login_ok")) {

                    String[] dados = resultado.split(",");

                    Intent abreHome = new Intent(Login.this, Home.class);

                    abreHome.putExtra("idusu", dados[1]);
                    abreHome.putExtra("nomeusu", dados[2]);

                    startActivity(abreHome);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Usuário ou senha incorretos.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking for an index that doesn't exist inside of you array.

It seems like you're looking for two objects, not three, but you are looking in the wrong place.

You should edit your code to look like this:

```
abreHome.putExtra("idusu", dados[0]);
abreHome.putExtra("nomeusu", dados[1]);
```

Comment: thx, fixed that error, but now i get a new error on this line

uNome = getIntent().getExtras().getString("nomeusu");
        textViewN.setText(uNome);

you know why?

Answer (score 0):

You are splitting the string:

```
String[] dados = resultado.split(",");
```

And assuming there will be at least three pieces:

```
abreHome.putExtra("idusu", dados[1]);
abreHome.putExtra("nomeusu", dados[2]);
```

But looks like that's is not the case. Check for the length of `dados` before you go and access elements from it.

Comment: I believe he is attempting to start at 1, instead of 0, index.